# Does main queue get dispatched when app re-launches into background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

My app makes use of [UIBackgroundMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22), i.e. it gets relaunched by iOS when Bluetooth events occur even while the app is not active. Therefore Bluetooth events are dispatched by iOS onto a background queue (queue is specified by me).

Can I however dispatch code back to the main queue, i.e.

`DispatchQueue.main.async { }` (Swift)

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ })` (Objective-C)

and assume that its run loop is running, that is my blocks get dispatched? Or is the main queue suspended in background mode and thus I should avoid adding dispatching blocks to it?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same.

Comment: I made an experiment where iOS seems to run the main loop because the blocks get executed while the app was launched in background mode. I however cannot assume that iOS will _always_ behave like this. If it would continue running the main loop, this would make things much easier for my app because then I don't need thread synchronization cause I simply dispatch to the main queue when necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be safe to dispatch to the main queue while in the background.

When your app is in the background, everything it does is technically done on background threads because the system marks your app as a lower priority. However, in order for the system to let your code run it needs to at least have a main queue. Therefore, it is safe to assume you will have access to the main queue. You can create other work queues from there if you want, but everything will most likely be shoved onto the one background thread for execution, so you may not see much benefit.

Also note that testing background threading can be a little tricky. Background threads will always be executed and seem to never be shut down while in the simulator. The same happens when testing on a device if Xcode is connected and debugging. The system also lets your app run continuously for 10 minutes (last I checked, it's possible this has changed in the last year or two) after entering the background if needed, and after it will require something like the bluetooth event you mentioned to get additional time in the background.

Source: An unfortunate amount of experience dealing with backgrounded apps.

Comment: Are you sure about 10 minutes? Documentation says apps have 10 _seconds_ when switching to background mode before getting suspended.

Comment: Ahh right, 10 seconds unless you have a background service going (like location updates), at that point I think the system will let that location updates continue for a max of 10 minutes. Unless of course something else gives your app more background time, like a significant location change or a bluetooth update. Bottom line is when building apps to run in the background you need to be prepared to be shut down at any moment.